# How to correctly use data binding in iron-image scr attribute?

Tags: data-binding, polymer-1.0

My Problem is very similiar to this one:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-image/issues/39

```
         <iron-image  class="avatar" placeholder="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" size="contain" src="[[item.svgPath]]" preload ></iron-image> 

         <iron-image  class="avatar" placeholder="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" size="contain" src="../images/sampleSVG/resistor.svg" preload ></iron-image>

  [[item.svgPath]] // "../images/sampleSVG/resistor.svg"
```

This only displays the image once. The iron-image with the data binding does not load. In my Network log i get the same file two times, once loaded successfully and once with an 404 error.

I guess the problem has to do with the loading circle of the dom and that the tag in already interpreted when the data binding takes place.

How do i avoid the 404 error produced by the image tag a binded scr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solotion to the problem myself. It actually is stated very cleary in the link i provided in my Question. When including the scr of an image via data binding, the root document changes from the current path to app/.

So insteat of

```
item.svgPath = "../images/sampleSVG/resistor.svg"
```

it has to be

```
item.svgPath = "/scr/images/sampleSVG/resistor.svg"
```